# Blog and Categories are not syncing in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, categories

I am pulling a blog together on SP and have about 45 categories to list. When creating the list I had no problem. However, as soon as I tried to modify to show all / filter or group categories in the blog it no longer synced to the content when I selected that custom view.

The only list that works is the "summary view", which doesn't allow me to apply any modifications to it. In "summary view", not all the categories are displayed for site users. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try replicating the summary view or creating a new view in SharePoint designer, which would then allow you to edit the view as necessary. This is also the method I use to create custom views for promoted links webparts.